# Feature Request: ability to not load the deleted answers after hitting 10k

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

I find viewing everyone else's deleted answers kind of distracting, and sometimes it's hard to not pass judgement when viewing some of them. Any chance of getting an option to be able to just not load them?

Comment: Sounds like a simple greasemonkey script, do you care about viewing deleted questions?

Comment: Ha ha... I knew a greasemonkey answer was inevitable ;)  I don't really care about questions as much.

Comment: Did you ever get a greasemonkey script to hide the mess?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would be happy if all the deleted answers were simply at the end regardless of their votes or answer/edit time.

Comment: Agreed. See the top related link on the right to all who agree.

Comment: This would be a fine solution too.

Comment: I could go for this. In fact, it might be technically better than mine. Less ajaxy stuff happening might be better.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps something like the "show more comments" would be good, so you can see where there is a deleted post, but it's a one line message that doesn't show anything other than a post was deleted.