# Ability to see deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

I know 10k users can see them, vote to permanently delete them, etc., but I'd like the ability to **see** them for users with lower rep (let's say 5000).

You couldn't act on them, but you could see them, and potentially leave comments for the 10k users to see.

Comment: What's the benefit here?

Comment: And then you'll get 5k users coming here posting dupe requests about getting those deleted answers hidden from their view.

Comment: Since you can't comment on a deleted post I really don't see what value this adds?

Comment: @random `hidden`. there should be an option to hide them for *anyone*, just as there should be an option to *show them* for the rest '<10|5|n k' of us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they were to bring it in, the users at the 5k mark will take it to Meta (and of course the lazy who just post on SO and wait for migration) and probably see more dupe requests wanting to have [deleted answers be hidden from their view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/get-these-stinking-deleteds-out-of-my-face).

Even as it is now, when you hit 10k, you don't exactly get to vote to close/delete answers, just questions.

On top of that you can't even comment or flag on a deleted post. So who gets to see it then and who will know you want to do something about it?

Comment: I don't think that when someone posts a question on SO that belongs in a different Stack Exchange they are being lazy.  Could there be another reason?  People who take the time to learn about SO and actually participate in it are not people whom I would categorize as lazy.  Brother, you haven't seen lazy if you think those are the lazy people!

Comment: @Phillip This is an old thread. I believe random is talking about people who post obvious *meta* questions on SO and wait for them to be moved here. It's got nothing to do with this feature request anyways, and I have strong doubt that *"There was one question where I saw valuable answer (or comment) and then it got deleted."* will be enough fuel for this huge change. You might want to at least post an answer here with your arguments/ideas.

Comment: I asked a questions yesterday and found that someone answered it in detail pointwise. I skimmed through it and it was looking promising. I didnt get time to read it fully yesterday. But seems that today someone else has given more crispier answer and yesterday's answer is not there anymore!!! Dont know why that person has deleted that answe, but I wanted to have a look at it, because I like verbose pointwise answers. The new answer spans 3-4 lines though precise!!! still wanted look at the other answer. So, I am I believe letting users to have a look at deleted answer has some good.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old but this could be a useful feature. If anything, it could be a toggle in your profile. I've run into this just this week where I posted a question and someone answered it the first day. I checked their fiddle and everything was good. I didn't copy it at the time and I came back later to find it deleted for some reason. I don't think the admin deleted it since it was a correct answer, but now it's gone form my view and I can't ever see this answer again.

A toggle off by default would be a great addition. Not just for 5k users, but for everyone. There ARE times when people should be able to see them.

Comment: If you had marked it as the correct answer at the time that you discovered it was the correct answer like you know your supposed to they would not have been able to delete it.. but +1 because someone commented on an answer I posted before they deleted it and I wanna see wht the comment was, so this would be useful.

Comment: Hit the same thing today, but in this case it wasn't my question so I couldn't mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I had this same problem, except I pointed out a small error in the answer and the user decided to delete it, even though it got me 90% of the way and I was going to accept it as soon as I had figured out the last 10%.