# Make Seeing Deleted Answers Optional

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, privileges

When Stack Exchange site users reach [10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (or [2,000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) for beta sites) they can view deleted posts. This can be very useful but deleted answers stay in their default ordering unless sorted by votes, so viewing a question with a lot of deleted answers can be cumbersome if you only want to see non-deleted posts.

The [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) at [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) is a particularly good example:

[image]

Can we have an option to not show deleted answers?

---

This is not a dupe of [Feature Request: ability to not load the deleted answers after hitting 10k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23535) because, as [Alex said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269091/make-seeing-deleted-answers-optional?noredirect=1#comment872030_269091):

> That was posted 6 years ago and the resolution was to just simply sort deleted posts to the end. This is asking for the ability to toggle viewing them at all. It'd at least be nice to revisit the issue, 6 years later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feature Request: ability to not load the deleted answers after hitting 10k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/feature-request-ability-to-not-load-the-deleted-answers-after-hitting-10k)

Comment: @NathanTuggy That was posted 6 years ago and the resolution was to just simply sort deleted posts to the end. This is asking for the ability to toggle viewing them at all. It'd at least be nice to revisit the issue, 6 years later.

Comment: Yeah, it is not a dupe.

Comment: lol I was just thinking of this yesterday when I visited the Formatting Sandbox (on Meta) -- I only just got 10k so it was a complete shock! +1

Answer (score 17):

Taking MichaelT's feedback into consideration, I think this might be a good feature to have not as a general set-once-edit-later user preference, but as a potentially "uncached" option per question. That is, when a user with sufficiently high reputation visits a question, they have the ability to hide deleted answers with the click of a button. Then at the bottom of the page, a message akin to `X deleted answers not shown, click to show` could be present. When I say "uncached," I mean that the user's choice to hide deleted answers persists only as long as the user is on the page; the next time they visit it, the deleted answers would be visible again. This ensures that the user isn't always blind to deleted content but they're able to hide it when it's been noted and is simply "in the way."

Another idea would be to make the option to hide deleted answers only available to trusted users, i.e. those with 20,000+ reputation on Stack Overflow or 4,000+ reputation on beta sites. If these users are trusted with other moderation abilities, it's reasonable to assume that, in general, they would have the good judgment to use this privilege wisely along with the others.

Answer (score 2):

Upon reaching the moderator-tools privilege, users are expected to use it. This means seeing deleted posts to make sure other users aren't abusing 20k delete answer powers, or help bring posts that need attention to the diamond mod's attention.  There are too few users using the moderation tools now and being able to completely hide the posts is akin to sticking one's fingers in the ears and saying `la la la la the site quality is fine la la la`.

However, I certainly do sympathize with the "this is taking up too much room on the screen in views sorted by things other than votes."  To that end, I suggest that one be able to select an *abbreviated* view of deleted answers that can be expanded.

This abbreviated view would have the first line summary (one line, no more) of the answer if it wasn't deleted as spam or offensive (corresponding message if it was) and identification card (user name and identicon).

On a second line under the summary, there would be:

- deleted reason (by owner or by users)
- link to fully expand the answer
- post revision history
- comment count

This pink background post would be no taller than the two or three lines used by the user card.

Comment: "users are expected to use it" - So you're saying that this becomes pay to play when you have high rep?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I am saying that at high reputation, you are expected to care about the site quality and are expected to help moderate the site. Being able to turn this off defeats the *expectation* of community moderation that the Stack Exchange framework is based on.

Comment: That was an expectation? People would do it because they want to, not because they're told to.  I don't moderate on Open Source cause I had 3k rep and I had to, but because I wanted to which is likely the reason why I got my diamond there as well.

Comment: @Zizouz212 from [Help Center > Privileges > access to moderator tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) - "As one of our most experienced users, we're counting on you to guide the community and lead by example. You can... ... •View deleted posts ... which collectively allow you to help the elected community moderators in monitoring the site and helping to clean up messes." --- I can't say it better than the help documentation does.  There is an expectation.

Comment: "Can" and "allow" are both words implying the behaviour is optional and something you might choose to do. Not something that everybody is obliged to do.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was more focusing on the "we're counting on you to guide the community".  If this behavior isn't expected and encouraged, the community moderation portion of Stack Exchange would fall *entirely* upon the diamond mods.

Comment: @MichaelT It should be "encouraged", not "expected". There is a major difference between the two.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I stand by my "it is an expectation that community moderation is the main form of moderation on the site." As seen on other sites, if this isn't the case and everything falls on the diamond mods, things can go horribly awry. Its not just encouraged - it is the foundation of the site maintains its focus and quality. It is expected.

Comment: I want to be moderated by people who want to moderate. There are plenty of people who do, not just those with diamonds. I don't want to see anyone pressured into it.