# Collapse deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, self-delete

One or two answers that I've posted are (upon reflection) *so* bad and unrectifiable, that I've had to delete them.  Fortunately there is a button for this.

However, on the question page *I* can still see my "deleted" answers – in their entirety, taking up space, and highlighted in red/pink.
Ideally there would be a way to remove them completely, but presumably there is a good reason why this isn't an option.

**Can deleted answers be made to be collapsiable (with a toggle switch)?**
(so that I don't *have to* see my own blunders)

**Related:**
[Make Seeing Deleted Answers Optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269091/make-seeing-deleted-answers-optional)
[Hide deleted answer content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content)

Comment: Editing the answer into something like "Deleted for being inaccurate", "Deleted due to security flaws", "Posted here by accident",... etc. is generally acceptable.

Comment: Why are you continually looking at those particular questions?

Comment: @RobertLongson - I'm watching other answers roll in

Comment: Yes but why? Generally wanting to know the answer and knowing the answer are mutually exclusive. If in any one tag you're generally in the knowing the answer camp then answer and move on, if you're in the wanting to know the answer camp then why are you answering?

Comment: @Robert You can be part of both groups in the same tags, sometimes. So, maybe you thought you had a solution, but turns out you're wrong, and you're waiting to find out the solution(s) that other people might come up with.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I've posted embarrassing answers before. If I would be *that* concerned to seeing them again, I'd simply erase their contents. It's always possible to view the original content through the revision history, so nothing is lost permanently.

This might look like vandalism, as noted in the comments. That is reverted for *useful* content, and note that a bad question can be still useful if it has a good answer. But it might be a good idea to specify the reason why you erased the content, to convince moderators that this is just a one-off and you're not rage-quitting.

Comment: I know that's an option, but it just seems like it's working around the system.

Comment: That begs the question why that isn't considered vandalism. Perhaps address that in your answer?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum editing a question that can’t be deleted to remove the content is vandalism. Deleting all your answers as you rage-quit is vandalism. Replacing the content of an answer you deleted because it was wrong is not vandalism because far fewer people can see the content and the revision history is not lost. In other words: Vandalism is deliberately damaging *publicly visible content*.

Answer (score 3):

This idea definitely has merit, with caveats.
Not even so much for the embarrassment of your own question you'd rather was gone, but for 'highly active' questions with 8 or 10 utter garbage non-answers at the bottom of the page. Because of my slight OCD I'm often compelled to read them, even sometimes looking at the edit history for spam/impolite deletions. I know I'm completely wasting my time, but I do it anyway :\

For these to be simply 'gone forever' [or on a toggle for the terminally curious] - with appropriate voting/moderation if necessary, to avoid the aforementioned vandalism/rage quits - would be heaven.

This looks to perhaps be the master question on this topic, not yet in the sidebar, included for completeness - [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)